# AWS EC2 Spot request fulfillment waiter from PHP SDK waits indefinitely

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to get through the eventual consistency of a spot instance so I can assign it within my application. Here's what I've seen, from a fairly simple spot instance call.

The instance requested is immediately started (fast 15-30 second instance running state), but the waiter continues indefinitely.

I'm not sure if the issue lies with my code, the SDK, or AWS not fulfilling the request quickly.

```
$spotEc2Client = $this->sdk->createEc2([]);

// Create instance via spot request
$result        = $spotEc2Client->requestSpotInstances($spotConfig);
$spotResult    = $result->getPath('SpotInstanceRequests');
$spotRequestId = $spotResult[0]['SpotInstanceRequestId'];

$now = date("F d, Y H:i:s A");
echo "Spot Request ID is: $spotRequestId\n";
echo "Starting at $now MST\n";
$spotEc2Client->waitUntil(
    'SpotInstanceRequestFulfilled',
    [
        'SpotInstanceRequestId' => $spotRequestId,
        '@waiter' => [
            'before' => function (CommandInterface $command, $attempts) {
                $now = date("H:i:s");
                printf(
                    "[$now] About to send %s. Attempt %d\n",
                    $command->getName(),
                    $attempts
                );
            }
        ],
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
Spot Request ID is: sir-<my request id>
Starting at August 18, 2017 10:10:20 AM MST
[10:10:20] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 1
[10:10:21] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 2
[10:10:36] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 3
[10:10:52] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 4
[10:11:07] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 5
[10:11:23] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 6
[10:11:38] About to send DescribeSpotInstanceRequests. Attempt 7
```

Comparing the check times against the launch time:

[image: spot instance launch time]

I'm thinking I need to just do my own polling against `describeInstances` looking specifically for spot instances that are at running or init, and handle it on my own - because the call to `DescribeSpotInstanceRequests` goes on indefinitely as far as I've been able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I had misformatted my argument for the `SpotRequestId`. This was quickly and kindly pointed out to me by someone on AWS PHP SDK's github!

The formatting of my spot instance request required a plural and an array as an argument.

```
$spotEc2Client->waitUntil(
    'SpotInstanceRequestFulfilled',
    [
        'SpotInstanceRequestId' => $spotRequestId,
    ]
    ...
```

To Be:

```
$spotEc2Client->waitUntil(
    'SpotInstanceRequestFulfilled',
    [
        'SpotInstanceRequestIds' => [
            $spotRequestId
    ]
    ...
```

I think as an API user I would prefer an exception or maybe a warning for the incorrect argument but that's a discussion for another place.